# Styling td, divide cells by months

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1st version - http://www.vrijemeusibeniku.com/weather/tablica-svipodaci.php?year=2014&data=minmaxt
works great but because of a colspan on february borders dont work properly

2st version - http://www.vrijemeusibeniku.com/weather/tablica-svipodaci2.php?year=2014&data=minmaxt
i have put colspan=1 but as a result data went in wrong cells

3st version - http://www.vrijemeusibeniku.com/weather/tablica-svipodaci4.php?year=2014&data=minmaxt
trying to style them with jquery. so far i have this code

```
$('tr:has(.smallfont)').each(function(){
    $(this).children('td:odd').css('border-right', '3px solid #555'); 
});
```

I believe I need some if statement, ie 'Jquery, pls style every td in that row with

```
('td:odd').css('border-right', '3px solid #555');
```

but if you get to td.nondate then switch and style with every td:even until you get to next td.nondate, then switch again.
I hope I make sense

Following of course didnt work...

```
  $('tr:has(.smallfont)').each(function(){
$(this).children().each(function(){

if ($(this).hasClass("nondate")) {
    $(this).children('td:odd').css('border-right', '3px solid #555'); 
   }
else {
    $(this).children('td:even').css('border-right', '3px solid #555'); 
}
});

});
```

Comment: you really shouldn't be using JS to style a table. [Use CSS instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Also, 2nd & 3rd

Comment: Well I agree completely but in this case I dont see any other option as I need a conditional statement..